# Logic involving graphics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that each class of the three below represents a different species and this graph represents a characteristic of them. How many species are possible to differentiate with this characteristic alone?

[image]

a. All three, because they are visually separated.
b. Only the gray, because it is more distant from the others.
c. Only black and red, as they are closer.
d. Only the red one, for being constant.
e. Only black, for having a defined pattern.

In the chart below there are three different classes of points, represented in different colors. Suppose that this distribution represents a common characteristic. Is this characteristic good for differentiating classes?

[image]

a. Yes, the points are close.
b. Yes, the points are mixed.
c. Yes, because it is easy to separate all points.
d. No, the points are far apart.
e. No, because there is a clear separation.

I found these two questions in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848310129) logic book ... I really can't see how to solve them using a pure logic approach. Isn't knowledge of at least functions and statistics required? Can you give me a tip to solve?